# Why is blade checking both if and elseif?

Tags: if-statement, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Normally when I check like this (see code below) and the first `if` is `true`, the `elseif` should skipped. In my case it shows both `layouts.app` and `layouts.donor.master` what am I not understanding here?

```
@if(auth()->guard('web')->check())
    @extends('layouts.app')
@elseif(auth()->guard('donor')->check())
    @extends('layouts.donor.master')
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the `@extends` is ignoring the if completely so I had to go another way around.

```
@extends(auth()->guard('donor')->check() ? 'layouts.donor.master' : 'layouts.app')
```

this worked, for me.